# TFS Detailed history in csv format

Tags: tfs, history, xls

When i generate a tfs detailed history output, i get it in the below format. is there a possiblity to convert this to csv format? anyone who has an idea of writing a conversion script please help on how it can done.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Changeset: 241
User: 52476
Date: Saturday, May 31, 2014 3:54:49 AM

Comment:
  Merged the changes from Integration branch to Main branch

Items:
  merge, edit $/Ace/Main/sWFA/cWFA/Form1.cs
  merge, edit $/Ace/Main/sWFA/cWFA/Program.cs
  merge, edit $/Ace/Main/sWFA/cWFA/Rama.txt
  merge, edit $/Ace/Main/sWFA/cWFA/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
  merge, edit $/Ace/Main/sWFA/cWFA/Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
  merge, edit $/Ace/Main/sWFA/cWFA/Test/Ramatest.txt

Check-in Notes:
  Code Reviewer:
    Prasad
  Manager_approval:
    Done
  Performance Reviewer:
    Mano
  Security Reviewer:
    Akhil

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So what would the fields in your CSV file be?

Comment: The fields will be                                               Changeset User Date Comment Items Check-in Notes Code Reviewer Manager_approval Performance Reviewer Security Reviewer